# Can I create an alias to an inherited method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, alias, python-decorators

I have a quite complex class hierarchy in my Python program. The program has many tools, which are either simulators or compilers. Both kinds share some methods, so there is a `Shared` class as a base class for all classes. A strip-down example looks like this:

```
class Shared:
  __TOOL__ = None

  def _Prepare(self):
    print("Preparing {0}".format(self.__TOOL__))


class Compiler(Shared):
  def _Prepare(self):
    print("do stuff 1")
    super()._Prepare()
    print("do stuff 2")

  def _PrepareCompiler(self):
    print("do stuff 3")
    self._Prepare()
    print("do stuff 4")


class Simulator(Shared):
  def _PrepareSimulator(self):   # <=== how to create an alias here?
    self._Prepare()           


class Tool1(Simulator):
  __TOOL__ = "Tool1"

  def __init__(self):
    self._PrepareSimulator()

  def _PrepareSimulator(self):
    print("do stuff a")
    super()._PrepareSimulator()
    print("do stuff b")
```

Can I define method `Simulator._PrepareSimulator` as an alias to `Simulator/Shared._Prepare`?

I know I can create local aliases like: `__str__ = __repr__`, but in my case `_Prepare` is not known in the context. I have no `self` nor `cls` to reference this method.

Could I write a decorator to return `_Prepare` instead of `_PrepareSimulator`? But how would I find `_Prepare` in the decorator?

Do I need to adjust the method binding too?

Comment: You can define `_PrepareSimulation` as an alias to `Shared._Prepare` thus: `_PrepareSimulation = Shared._Prepare`. But I'm not at all sure why you'd want to. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You have `_PrepareSimulation` and `_PrepareSimulator` - are the different or was that a typo?

Comment: typo :) Classes in higher level can overwrite methods and thus plugin their logic if needed. Most classes use the functionality from base classes

Comment: You don't need a base class just to get some common methods, Python has Duck Typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create a decorator based solution, which ensures type safety. The first decorator annotates an alias to a local method. It is needed to safe the aliases target. The second decorator is needed to replace the `Alias` instance and check if the alias points to a method in the type hierarchy.

**Decorators / Alias definition:**

```
from inspect import getmro

class Alias:
  def __init__(self, method):
    self.method = method

  def __call__(self, func):
    return self

def HasAliases(cls):
  def _inspect(memberName, target):
    for base in getmro(cls):
      if target.__name__ in base.__dict__:
        if (target is base.__dict__[target.__name__]):
          setattr(cls, memberName, target)
          return
      else:
        raise NameError("Alias references a method '{0}', which is not part of the class hierarchy: {1}.".format(
          target.__name__, " -> ".join([base.__name__ for base in getmro(cls)])
        ))

  for memberName, alias in cls.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(alias, Alias):
      _inspect(memberName, alias.method)

  return cls
```

**Usage example:**

```
class Shared:
  __TOOL__ = None

  def _Prepare(self):
    print("Preparing {0}".format(self.__TOOL__))


class Shared2:
  __TOOL__ = None

  def _Prepare(self):
    print("Preparing {0}".format(self.__TOOL__))


class Compiler(Shared):
  def _Prepare(self):
    print("do stuff 1")
    super()._Prepare()
    print("do stuff 2")

  def _PrepareCompiler(self):
    print("do stuff 3")
    self._Prepare()
    print("do stuff 4")


@HasAliases
class Simulator(Shared):
  @Alias(Shared._Prepare)
  def _PrepareSimulatorForLinux(self):    pass

  @Alias(Shared._Prepare)
  def _PrepareSimulatorForWindows(self):  pass


class Tool1(Simulator):
  __TOOL__ = "Tool1"

  def __init__(self):
    self._PrepareSimulator()

  def _PrepareSimulator(self):
    print("do stuff a")
    super()._PrepareSimulatorForLinux()
    print("do stuff b")
    super()._PrepareSimulatorForWindows()
    print("do stuff c")

t = Tool1()
```

Setting `@Alias(Shared._Prepare)` to `@Alias(Shared2._Prepare)` will raise an exception:

> NameError: Alias references a method '_Prepare', which is not part of the class hierarchy: Simulator -> Shared -> object.